# Haskell what does var <- get mean?

Tags: haskell

I have run into this code but I have no idea what does `grid <- get` do? How do we know that this grid is our current grid? We are not passing it as an argument. So how can we use it to grab rows using that?

```
data Grid = Grid [Row]
type GridState a = State Grid a

initializeGrid :: GridState ()
initializeGrid = do
        setPositionToColor 2 0 Alive


setPositionToColor :: Int -> Int -> CellState -> GridState ()
setPositionToColor x y color = do
        grid <- get
        let rows = getRows grid
            ...
        put newState

getRows :: Grid -> [Row]
...
```

Answer (score 5):

The `State` monad is effectively hiding the fact that every function takes a state value as input and includes a (possibly changed) state in the output. `get` effectively just returns that hidden argument.

It's clearer if you write your function without using `State`.

```
-- State Grid a == Grid -> (Grid, a)
setPositionToColor :: Int -> Int -> Color -> Grid -> (Grid, ())
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When you call `setPositionToColor 2 0 Alive`, you don't actually color any particular element of your grid, because there is no grid involved yet. You just get back a function that, when *it* is called with a `Grid`, will produce the newly modified `Grid`.

Without the `Monad` instance, every call to `setPositionToColor` would need that additional argument, and it would return a new `Grid` to be passed to the next call. Your code would look something like

```
let (grid1,_) = setPositionToColor x1 y1 color1 initialGrid
    (grid2,_) = setPositionToColor x2 y2 color2 grid1
    (grid3,_) = setPositionToColor x3 y3 color3 grid2
    (grid4,_) = setPositionToColor x4 y4 color4 grid3
in grid4
```

---

All the `Monad` instance does is let take care of passing the intermediate `Grid` values from one function to the next; all you need to do is supply `initialGrid` as the argument to `runState`, which actually starts the calls to the composed `State` action.

```
-- Back to setPositionToColor :: Int -> Int -> Color -> State Grid a
let allFour = setPositionToColor x1 y1 color1 >>= (\() ->
              setPositionToColor x2 y2 color2 >>= (\() ->
              setPositionToColor x3 y3 color3 >>= (\() ->
              setPositionToColor x3 y3 color4)))
in runState allFour initialGrid
```

or, because we don't actually care about the `()` value being returned from each call,

```
let allFour = setPositionToColor x1 y1 color1 >>
              setPositionToColor x2 y2 color2 >>
              setPositionToColor x3 y3 color3 >>
              setPositionToColor x3 y3 color4
in runState allFour initialGrid
```

Using `do` notation,

```
let allFour = do
   setPosition x1 y1 color1
   setPosition x2 y2 color2
   setPosition x3 y3 color3
   setPosition x4 y4 color4
in runState allFour initialGrid
```

Answer (score 3):

Your grid is "contained" within the `State` monad. See how your `GridState a` is defined? It's an alias for `State Grid a`. It says that `GridState` is a state monad, which "carries" a state of type `Grid`.

The way that the `State` monad "contains" your grid is also relatively straightforward: you can [look it up](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.0/transformers-0.5.2.0/src/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#StateT), it's just a function that takes the state as parameter. A computation in this monad simply "tunnels" this parameter through the steps, but that happens behind the scenes, invisibly for you. The compiler desugars the `do` syntax into successive applications of the `>>=` operator, and for the `State` monad this operator "tunnels" the state parameter from one computation to the next.

The `get` function is a monadic operation in the `State` monad. It merely returns the state that is "contained" in the monad at this point (you can [look up the function too](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.0/transformers-0.5.2.0/src/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#get)).

So the way to read the line `grid <- get` is "*take out the current state of the `State` monad, and give it the name `grid`*".